# Autoconf, how to discover the numbers of parameters for a lib function?

Tags: c, autotools, configure, autoconf, libtool

Suppose I've a portability problem caused by this function `foo` that can take one or two parameters depending on the system:

```
#include "config.h"
#ifdef FOO_ONEPARAM
    #define FOO(a) foo(a)
#else
    #define FOO(a) foo(a,b)
#endif
```

How do I set properly `FOO_ONEPARAM` after disconvering it with `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the [GNU Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/index.html#Top) to see if someone has written a macro for `foo` already.  If not, you can use the method used by 
[this macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_func_which_gethostbyname_r.html#ax_func_which_gethostbyname_r) at the GNU Autoconf Archive to write your own, which is superficially similar to what you're already doing.  There's probably several macros at the archive that do something like this (for old functions mostly), this was just the first one I ran across.